# db2 - Update statement using subselect with case

Tags: db2

I want to do an update statement according to a result of a subquery

For example :

```
Update TABLE1 
set A= (Select Count(*) from TABLE2 ) 
if the value of count is 0 then Update the value of A to be 0 Else set A = 1;
```

So could you please advice me how can I do it?

I tried the following but I got a syntax error :

```
SELECT count(*) as TC
 CASE
   WHEN TC > 0 
   THEN '1'
   ELSE '0'
   END  AS dum
   FROM Event E where E.Type= 'CANCELLING';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CASE` is perfectly suitable:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET A = 
CASE 
   WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE2) > 0 THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Thanks AnatoliiG for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @count int
set @count=Select Count(*) from TABLE2 

if @count=0
BEGIN
Update TABLE1 
set A=0
end
else
Update TABLE1 
set A=1
```

Comment: Thanks Kiet for you reply :)